# How to start AlarmManager on open application?

Tags: android

I'm newbie in Android. I have simple application and I would like set daily notification. How is the best way for this?

I found two possibilities:

1. On boot time, but this is not good for me. I want to start my notification only if I open my application and until if it isn't destroy. Otherwise, this requires the use of permissions.
2. In custom class which extends class Application, but in this class I don't have access to Intent and SystemService.

Maybe can I use services for this? But how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have several options:

**JobScheduler**

If your minSdk >= 21, you can use [JobScheduler](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobScheduler.html). You can create periodic task using [builder](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/job/JobInfo.Builder.html). This is right solution for [Doze](https://developer.android.com/training/monitoring-device-state/doze-standby.html).

**Firebase JobDispatcher**

If you want support older than Lollipop, you should use Firebase [JobDispacher](https://github.com/firebase/firebase-jobdispatcher-android). It is very similar to JobScheduler and is based on firebase. User must have google play services

**AlarmManager**

Oldschool tool for this job and not compatible with doze. You should avoid it.

First two solutions allow you persist job across the system reboot.

Comment: Thanks, but how can I start JobScheduler automatically, withour reaction of user?

Comment: You can setup jobs anytime while your application is running. You can set up job on the first application launch. Another solution is to use `BOOT_COMPLETED` broadcast message, but you also need `RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED` permission.